# How to send signal to JVM created by JNI_CreateJavavm call?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, signals, pid

Is there any possibility that I can directly send signal to a Java virtual machine which is created by calling `JVM_CreateJavavm` in native C/C++ code?

e.g.:

For a normal Java process, say its pid is 12345, I can send a signal 3 to it like this ...
kill -3 12345, and hopefully I could trigger javacore or heapdump by changing JVM configurations.

However if the JVM is created thru JNI API and wrapped inside a C/C++ application, only the native process's PID is visible, in that case if I send signal to that process, the whole process is just terminated and seems the JVM cannot receive the signal at all.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no separate process for the JVM. The JVM is just running in the process that called it. I don't think that Sun documents a way to use those signal handlers via the invocation interface.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scribd.com/doc/13119378/If-JNI-based-application-is-crashing-check-signal-handling